# Can't add shortcuts to home page on galaxy s4

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, launcher, home-screen-shortcuts

Yesterday I upgraded my Galaxy s4 from KitKat to lollipop and since then I can't have shortcuts on my home page. By that I mean every time I create one at first everything is good but then a little time passes and it magically disappears and I have to make a new one but then it disappears too... how can I create shortcuts without them going away?

Thank you!

Comment: Since the S4 is a pretty old device, I assume that you're using a custom ROM. Which one? Also, which launcher are you now using?

Comment: I've been using Nova Launcher and I like it a little better than the stock launcher https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher&hl=en